# Within a five-mile radius [of or from] my house?

Tags: prepositions

As far as I know, **"within a five-mile radius of my house"** is correct. What about **"within a five-mile radius from my house"**? It sounds even more natural to me but I'm not really sure if it's grammatical.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that the *from* version is **wrong**, but there certainly is a standard template, “within *d* of *p*,” where *d* is a distance and *p* is a place or location.

Comment: Collins Dictionary [provides examples](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/radius) with _radius of, radius from_, and _radius around_.

Comment: It's the use of "within" which seems to be causing your confusion:  Compare: **within five miles of my house** with  **five miles from my house**.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's the word **within** that causes the problem in your example.

You would typically say:

> within a five-mile radius of my house

But if you remove **within**, you can say:

> a file-mile radius from my house

I'm not exactly sure why, but it might be because the second example is more specific than the first. Similarly, these examples are even more specific:

> five miles from my house
> a five-mile drive from my house